# Wait for element error_handler.check_response(response)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this code but after run i have error at WebDriverWait :

```
../../../../../../../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py:80: in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
../../../../../../../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py:633: in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
../../../../../../../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:321: in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)



class Consultations(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

    opt = Options()
    opt.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    opt.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    opt.add_argument("--kiosk")
    opt.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    # Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
    opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 1,
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 1,
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1
    })

    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opt)
    self.base_url = test_qa_url



def test_consultation_CCI_WBA_001(self):
    loginPage = LoginPage.Loginpage(self.driver)
    consultationPage = ConsultationsPage.Consultationspage(self.driver)
    homePage = HomePage.Homepage(self.driver)
    self.driver.get("https://test-maville.bciti.info/")

    # Login ass admin
    loginPage.check_login_page_loaded()
    loginPage.enter_username()
    loginPage.enter_password()
    loginPage.click_login()
    time.sleep(5)

    # Click on admin tab
    homePage.click_admin_tab()
    time.sleep(12)

    # Click on Consultation
    homePage.click_admin_consultations()
    time.sleep(30)

    # Click on Add consultation button
    element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, admin_consultations_add_consultations_button)))

    element.click()
    time.sleep(8)
```

Comment: Just looking at the code and nothing seems to be wrong here -- the error message could be from wait timing out if Add Consultation button never appears. Could you post driver page source / HTML code on the page when that line is run? This will help track down the issue.

Comment: Also, I don't see this in your code, have you imported `expected_conditions`? `from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`

Comment: Yes i import the expected_conditions from from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

This is the html code :
<button class="md-primary md-raised cc-header-item md-button" type="button" ng-transclude="" id="adminCreateConsultation" ng-click="AdminConsultations.goCreateConsultation()" aria-label="Créer une nouvelle consultation" md-labeled-by-tooltip="md-tooltip-307"><i class="fa fa-plus ng-scope"></i></button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated failing code sample from the asker, with error on `.click()`:

```
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until( EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tab-content-2"]/div/md-content/div[9]/a/span'))).click()
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until( EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'adminCreateConsultation'))).click()
```

I think the issue here has to do with concatenating `wait.until` and `.click()` operations. Try splitting up the code like this:

```
# Wait for the element to exist
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tab-content-2"]/div/md-content/div[9]/a/span')))

# then click it
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="tab-content-2"]/div/md-content/div[9]/a/span").click()

# Wait for the element to exist
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'adminCreateConsultation')))

# then click it -- need to use Javascript click for this element
createConsultationButton = driver.find_element_by_id("adminCreateConsultation")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", createConsultationButton)
```

Comment: Thank now the click is working fine but i have a problem with the wait before this action if i delete time.sleep between the two action its fail:
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tab-content-2"]/div/md-content/div[9]/a/span'))).click()  

element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'adminCreateConsultation'))).click()

Comment: Does the `wait.Until` throw an error message of any kind?

Comment: i have this message :
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py:80: in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py:633: in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:321: in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

Comment: I have updated my answer to potentially fix the issue you just mentioned.

Comment: I have the same error on the second click, the first work but the second not working :(
and under this error :
self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x10a9e3910>

Comment: Is the code failing on `.click()` or on `wait.until(EC...` ?

Comment: failing on .click()

Comment: try `element = driver.find_element_by_id("adminCreateConsultation")` then `print(element)` to see if driver is finding correct element.

Comment: element="fb260e8b-4b4b-479f-b35e-2c993f904acb"

Comment: The  element is printing correctly, so it looks like the element is found but cannot be clicked. Let's try clicking it with javascript: `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)`

Comment: FINALY ITS WORKING FIN, THANKS A LOT YOU ARE THE BEST

Comment: Updated my post with `driver.execute_script` code to click `adminCreateConsultation` button.